# not able to access Django project through Docker Compose

Tags: python, django, docker, docker-compose

I have created a simple Docker file for DJango project and when I issue docker run, I am able to access through browser.

docker run -p 8000:8000 s3bucket-ms:1

Here is the Docker File:

```
FROM python:3.6.7-alpine
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
COPY ./requirements.txt /requirements.txt
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN apk update \
    && apk add postgresql-dev gcc python3-dev musl-dev
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app
ADD ./s3bucket /app/
EXPOSE 8000
CMD ["python", "./manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"]
```

However, when I am using Docker Compose , i can't access the project through the browser.

Here is the docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

services:
  web:
    build: .
    command: python ./manage.py runserver 8000
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
```

With Docker Compose , I also commented CMD within Docker File. 
Output from Docker Compose UP

```
web_1  | Run 'python manage.py migrate' to apply them.
web_1  | February 17, 2020 - 14:29:22
web_1  | Django version 3.0.3, using settings 's3bucket.settings'
web_1  | Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
web_1  | Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
```

Am I missing something? Any help is appreciated.
Thanks,

Comment: In `docker-compose` you have to listen to `0.0.0.0` not `127.0.0.1`.

Answer (score 0):

Add `EXPOSE 8000` on your Dockerfile

**Update1**:

With docker run

```
docker run \
    -v /path/to/s3bucket:/app \ # absolute path
    -p 8000:8000 \
    s3bucket-ms:1
```

With docker-compose

```
version: '3'

services:
  web:
    build: .
    command: python ./manage.py runserver 8000
    volumes:
      - /path/to/s3bucket:/app # absolute path
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
```

More infos on https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/

Comment: make sure you container rebuild properly.
Then clear cache running command
`docker network prune`

Comment: I'm sorry, you forgot to share your project inside you container. I think you simply need to user volumes. you dont use it on docker run or your docker-compose.

Comment: I am not following you here ..
I just added the following line in the dockerfile.
COPY ./s3bucket /app/